# Show that $(b-a)[I(0\le a\le b)-I(b\le a\le0)]=\int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Show that
$$(b-a)\cdot[I(0\le a\le b)-I(b\le a\le0)]=\int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx,$$
where $I(\cdot)$ is the index function.

By definition, this equation can be verified. Does it have an straightforward proof or how can one observe this equation?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can evaluate both sides of equality and prove it. Let us first evaluate the integral on the RHS. consider two cases:
$$\begin{align} &1. \quad a \ge 0 \\
&2. \quad a<0 \\
\end{align}$$
For the first case we have $I(a\le0) = 0$, so the integral boils down to $\int_0^bI(a\le x)dx$. 
This integral is equal to: $$ \int_0^bI(a\le x)dx = \begin{cases}   0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \;\ a \ge b\\  \int_a^bI(a\le x)dx  \qquad a<b\end{cases} = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \qquad \; a\ge b \\ (b-a) \quad a<b \end{cases}$$

For the second case we have $I(a\le0) = 1$ which means $$\int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx = \int_0^b(I(a\le x)-1)dx = \left(\int_0^bI(a\le x)dx \right) -b = \int_0^bdx-b = 0 $$
Altogether we have $$ \int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx = \begin{cases}0  \qquad \qquad \quad a\ge 0 , b\ge0 , a\ge b\\ (b-a) \quad  \;\;\;\;\; a\ge0 , b\ge 0, a<b\\ 0 \qquad \qquad  \quad a<0,b\ge0 \end{cases}$$

since in this case $a<0$.

Also we had in mind that $b>0$. If $b<0$ it is similar to the previous state with a little change in conditions:

$$ \int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx = \begin{cases}0  \qquad \qquad \quad a\ge 0 , b<0 , \\ -(b-a) \quad  \;\; a<0 , b< 0, a > b\\ 0 \qquad \qquad 
 \quad a<0,b<0, b<a\end{cases}$$

Please notice that when $a<0,b<0,a>b$ this means $|a|<|b|$ so the second one is obtained as follow: $$\int_0^b[I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx  = \int_0^b[I(a\le x)-1]dx  = \int_b^0[1-I(a\le x)]dx =\int_b^a dx  = (a-b)=-(b-a) \qquad \qquad \text{when} \qquad a<0 , b< 0, a > b $$
 Now consider the LHS. for the LHS we have

$$(b-a)\cdot[I(0\le a\le b)-I(b\le a\le0)] = \begin{cases} 0  \qquad \qquad \quad a\ge 0 , b<0 , \\ -(b-a) \quad  \;\; a<0 , b< 0, a > b\\ 0 \qquad \qquad 
 \quad a<0,b<0, b<a \\ 0  \qquad \qquad \quad a\ge 0 , b\ge0 , a\ge b\\ (b-a) \quad  \;\;\;\;\; a\ge0 , b\ge 0, a<b\\ 0 \qquad \qquad  \quad a<0,b\ge0 \end{cases}$$ which are exactly the same we got from the RHS, only a simple inspection is needed. Sorry for exhaustive explanation but i always wanted someone to explain such integrals to me this way not short and intractable solution. Hope this would do.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer and detailed explanation.

Comment: my pleasure dude!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\int_0^b$ as $\int_a^b-\int_a^0$. Evaluate
$
J:=\int_a^b [I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx$ by arguing two cases:

- If $a\le b$, then $I(a\le x)=1$ when $x\in[a,b]$, so
  $$J=\int_a^b[1-I(a\le0)]dx=\int_a^b I(a>0)dx=(b-a)I(a>0).\tag1$$
- If $a>b$, then $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$, and $I(a\le x)=0$ when $x\in[b,a]$, so
  $$J=-\int_b^a [I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx=\int_b^aI(a\le0)dx=(a-b)I(a\le0).\tag2$$

Combining these two cases gives
$$
\begin{align}J&=(b-a)I(a>0)I(a\le b)+(a-b)I(a\le0)I(a>b)\\
&=(b-a)I(0<a\le b)-(b-a)I(b<a\le0).\tag3
\end{align}$$
This agrees with the LHS of the asserted identity up to some fussiness with $<$ vs $\le$; formula (3) is correct for the edge case $b>a=0$ whereas the stated LHS is wrong.

This implies the second integral $\int_a^0$ must be zero, which can be verified by plugging $b=0$ into (3). (Apply the general case to the special case!)

---

EDIT: A slicker proof:

1. Show that $\int_a^bI(a\le x)\,dx=\int_a^b  I(a\le b)\,dx$ by arguing cases $a\le b$ and $a>b$.
2. Show that $I(a\le b)-I(a\le0)=I(0<a\le b)-I(b<a\le0)$ by writing
   $$
   I(a\le b)-I(a\le0)=
   I(a\le b)\big[I(a>0)+I(a\le0)\big] - I(a\le0)\big[I(a\le b)+I(a>b)\big]
   $$
   or by inspecting a picture in the $(a,b)$ plane.
3. Steps 1 and 2 imply
   $$
   \int_a^b [I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]dx=
   (b-a)\big[I(0<a\le b)-I(b<a\le0)\big],
   $$
   and Step 1 shows that
   $
   \int_a^0 [I(a\le x)-I(a\le0)]\,dx=0$, so we're done!